Wildcard search for colours hex code in Notepad++
I have an application that produces object files. Each object has a .mtl text file.
These .mtl files contains a 6 figure hex code defining a colour. The application generates random colour hex codes, i.e., c2cf1a.
Therefore, I want to find and change all hex codes with numbers in them to a defined 6 figure string, i.e., aaaaaa.
An example line of text: map_Kd baked_303030_brick.dds
I am using Notepad++, but I'm unable to find the correct regex expressions to achieve this.

what regex have you tried?

I have tried \d{6}_  as there is always an underscore following the hexcode. It sort of works but only on a few cases which I find odd.

\d{6}_ seems to work only on numbers. Strings with letters and numbers do not work. Is the d correct for all characters or how do I get it to see numbers and letters in a 6 figure string? Thanks for your interest.

I have solved it myself by using \w(6)_ which worked fine. Found only 6 figure strings ending with underscore and only containing letters and numbers and omitting any spaces.

I am trying a negative look behind:     (?:(?<!aaaaaa )(?<!bbbbbb )(?<!cccccc ))\w(6)_      But not sure if the syntax is correct or a look ahead is better. This currently does not work.

Please use a question for a single question and don't alter its Text many times to another questions when your original question is solved. Please create a new question instead.

Please do not edit this question to ask other questions, that is not how Stack Overflow works. Instead, post another question while linking to this one if you think it provides necessary context. Also, please take the [tour], and read [ask] to get familiar with how Stack Overflow works. Good luck.

My apoligies. New to this forum. I am all sorted now. Many thanks to all for your help.

The solution was using the regex \w(6)_. Provided by the author himself.
